# no matching function for call to 'fopen'

Tags: fopen, rcpp

I want to call `fopen` within my cpp function, however, `Rcpp` always complains about "no matching function for call to 'fopen'".
So duplicated exactly the some code from https://github.com/hadley/xml2/blob/9362d379e126a86091af8698a8987c51b5b230fe/src/xml2_doc.cpp and still have the same error.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void doc_write(std::string path){
  FILE* f = fopen(path.c_str(), 'r');
  fclose(f);
}
```

and the error is:

```
testc.cpp:6:36: error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]
```

Can someone point some hints on me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message tells you everything you need to know - you're trying to pass a `char` parameter where a `const char *` is required.
replace `'r'` with `"r"` that should fix it.

Comment: @baidao please accept this answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Thanks Akbari. I didn't know that quotes make difference.